How do I speed up Git submodule init + update
I have a repo with a lot of submodules, and it takes a long time to initialise all of them from a fresh checkout.
git submodule update --init

seems to do everything in series, when the operation seems eminently parallelizable. any ideas?

After a bunch of experimentation, I came up with
# start with "init".  this step cannot be parallelised, 
# because every operation tries to update .git/config and will fail with locking errors
# but this step is quite fast because it's all in the local filesystem
git submodule init

# now list all submodule paths, and pipe them to xargs to do the update part
# this give a big boost because it's the part that downloads from the internet.
git submodule status | cut -d" " -f2 | xargs -n1 -P0 git submodule update

always keen to hear of any even-better options!
(took me from 25s down to about 5s total btw.)
